# Young adult science fiction book from the early 80s: alien race adept at martial arts

Tags: story-identification

It was a series of books about an alien race. They were very adept at martial arts, training their kids at an early age, and they would hire their services out to people they deemed worthy.

The main character and his best friend, a girl, discover something about a prospective client and wind up getting into a hand to hand fight with him. They were both young kids. The race decides to not work for this guy or his people. Later, the main character is off planet and as he's returning home, his planet is ravaged by radiation. He almost dies.

He is saved by either one or two other aliens, when they replace his skeleton with organic, living metal. He's basically turned into Wolverine without the regeneration or heightened senses.  Unfortunately, that's all I can remember about the books, and I was only able to read the first 2 in the series.

Comment: If gowenfahr has the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 21):

This is *[The Last Legionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_Legionary)* series, where the book people seem to remember was *Deathwing over Veynaa*.  Some of what you described comes from *Galactic Warlord*:

> The Overseers also explain that, since the radiation sickness had
> settled into his bones, they were forced to replace his entire
> skeleton—using an unbreakable alloy—effectively rendering Keill's
> bones unbreakable. They also reveal how they captured Keill so
> easily—a telepathic avian life form from another galaxy known only as
> 'Glr'.

This was the previously asked and answered [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/103152/20490).

[image: Galactic Warlord cover art]
[image: Deathwing over Veynaa cover art]

Comment: Also worth mentioning that the bad experience with a prospective client by Keill and Oni Wolda was in the prequel book Young Legionary.

Comment: Accepted answer at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47022/series-of-young-adult-science-fiction-books-from-early-1980s-about-last-of-a-rac

Comment: Wow. The replaced radioactive skeleton rings a bell. I actually read it in German: [Der Weltraumspion](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2308380). I remember that for a YA novel, there was quite a bit of violence, sadism and actual planetwide genocide between the covers. Well, it's all about getting prepared for the Real World I suppose.